how to prove $H'A' \perp OP $
I am currently preparing for a national mathematical Olympiad, and this problem comes from a training set provided by my coach. It focuses on advanced properties of triangle geometry, particularly involving orthocenters, reflections, and circles. These topics are crucial for many geometry problems in Olympiad exams, and I am trying to strengthen my understanding of them.
I have been working on this problem for a few days. While I have successfully solved most of the sub-problems, I am stuck on proving that $H'A' \perp OP $. This result seems to require deeper insight into the interplay between the orthocenter H' of △, the reflection ′ and the perpendicularity condition involving $OP $.
This question is important for me because mastering these types of problems will help me perform better in the Olympiad and deepen my understanding of triangle geometry. Any guidance or insight would be greatly appreciated.
Given an acute, scalene triangle $ \triangle ABC$ inscribed in the circle $ (O)$, let $ H $ be its orthocenter. Denote $A' $ and $ D $ as the reflections of $ A $ across $ BC $ and $ O $, respectively. Let $ P $ be a point on $ BC $ such that $ AP \perp OH $ (assuming $ A, D, P $ are not collinear). Let $H' $ be the orthocenter of $ \triangle ADP $.
a) Prove that if $ \angle BAC = 60^\circ $, then $ H'D $ passes through the midpoint of the minor arc $ BC $ of  (O) .
b) Prove that $H'A' \perp OP $, and if $\angle BAC = 45^\circ $, then $ H' $ and $ O $ are symmetric with respect to $ BC $.


I don't have a solution for you, but it might be worth noting that the conclusion implies that $H'A' \cap OP$ is the so-called $P$ "humpty" or "HM" point for $\triangle ADP$ — see eg here

wow, thank for P "humpty", it's a new term to me, i consider that!


Case 1:
$\angle BAC=60^o$:
Since D is reflect of A over O then AD is diameter of circle O. the Line H'D cross circle O at G. So $\angle AGD=90^o$. That is $H'D||HO$. We use the fact that if $\angle BAC=60^o $ then the bisector of BAC passes through the center of the nine point circle N.N is the mid point of HO. $PA\bot HO$ That means AP is the bisector of angle EAO. Now we use this fact that the bisector of angle between the diameter of circumcircle and altitude is also the bisector of the vertex which is one end of the diameter and the altitude is drawn from, that is AG is the bisector of BAC. Now AG is bisector of angle BAC and G is where the perpendicular bisector of BC bisects arc BC. In this way H'D passes through G which is the mid point of arc BC.
We have:
$H'P\bot AD$
$H'P\bot RV$ at V because H'R is diameter of the circumcircle of triangle ADH'. So:
$ RV||AD\Rightarrow Arc AR= Arc DV$
$\angle POQ=\frac{Arc A'D+ Arc AR}2$
$\angle VH'A'=\frac {Arc VD + Arc A'D}2$
Which means $\angle VH'A'=\angle POQ$
That is triangles PH'A' and POQ are similar since $\angle PQO=90^o$ then $angle H'A'P=90^o$
That is PA' or OP in perpendicular on H'A'.
For case 2 use following figure which clearly shows the situation and prove that H' coincides on O' , the reflect of O about BC.


Thank you for helping me solve the problem. However, could you clarify how to construct R, V? And why does A' lie on the circumcircle of triangle AH’D? If A' lie on the circumcircle, it’s ease to prove, and don’t need similar triangles

@J.Simpson, You'r welcome. I changed the picture. In new picture $O_1$ is the center of circumcircle of triangle H'AD. So R is other end of diameter H'D.  V is where the extension of altitude H'Q of triangle H'AD meets the circumcircle. As can be seen in picture BC is coincident on a diameter of circumcircle which is perpendicular on altitude AE. A' is reflect of A over BC , so it is on circumcircle.

I'm not sure I follow your proof that $H'A' \perp OP$ — in the general case $A'$ might not be on the circle $(H'AD)$

@sirous but could you explain how BC is a diameter of circumcircle of H’AD, or how BC goes through $O_1$?

@tkw according to results of P “humpty”, $H’, A’, A, D$ are concylic

@J.Simpson, that's true, but $A'$ is the $P$-humpty point only if $\angle BAC=60^o$, in general one needs to show that this point lies on the line $H'A'$

@tkw yes, that’s right, i got it

@J.Simpson, You can say that since CB is perpendicular bisector of AA' and A is on the circle then A' must Also be on the circle and also BC must be on diameter of the circle.

Let AR be the altitude. The altitude AR intersects the circle (ABC) at point J, and PJ intersects the circle (ABC) at point K. DP intersects the circle (ABC) at point M.
We have: AM ⊥ DM and H'A ⊥ PD (since H' is the orthocenter of triangle ADP), so A, M, H' are collinear. Therefore, H' is the intersection point of AM and KG, which implies H' lies on the polar line of point P.
We also know: APNK is a cyclic quadrilateral (since ∠AKP = ∠ADJ = ∠ANR), and these two circles intersect at points A and K. Hence, K is the center of the spiral similarity that transforms P into G and N into D. Therefore, triangles KPG and KND are similar, so ∠KGD = ∠KPC.
Since ∠KPC = ∠BPJ = ∠HPB = ∠HLR, and L is the midpoint of AG, and R is the midpoint of AA', it follows that RL is parallel to A'G. Since H'G || HL, we have ∠HLR = ∠H'GA'.
Thus, ∠H'GA' = ∠KGD, so A', G, K are collinear. Therefore, A' is the intersection point of AJ and GK, implying that A' lies on the polar line of P.
Hence, OP is perpendicular to H'A'

nice solution! a couple of typos i think: in paragraph 3 i think you mean "spiral similarity" not "homothety", and it's $\triangle KPN$ that is similar to $\triangle KGD$, not $\triangle KPG$. it might be worth mentioning that the claims about polars follow from Brokard's theorem (unless there is a simpler way to conclude this?)

Yes, thanks, that is spiral similarity, i modified.But i like your idea of P “Humpty”
